# how do I open files in my texteditor, which I created in python(tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter, sublimetext3

I am trying to make a simple text editor with python(tkinter) in Sublime Text 3 with the following code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

root=Tk()

def OpenFile():
    file_name=filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/Desktop\python", title="Select a File:", filetype=(("Txt Files",".txt"),("All Files","*.*")))
    content = open(file_name).read()
    txteditor.insert(END, content)
    
def SaveFile():
    myfile = filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension='.txt')
    if myfile is None:
        return
    content=txteditor.get(1.0,'end-1c')
    myfile.write(content)

root.iconbitmap(default='icon2.ico')
root.title('My Notepad')
txteditor=Text(root, width=50, height=20).pack()

openbtn=Button(root, text='Open', command=OpenFile)
openbtn.pack()

savebtn=Button(root, text='Open', command=OpenFile)
savebtn.pack()
```

but when I click open button, then the window appears but when I click on open button(after selecting the file to be opened), it gives error in line 10 [image: error I am getting when I run my code with Sublime Text 3 IDE(see in the image)]

Comment: When I run your program, nothing happens. Please make sure the code you show does *actually create the error you are asking about*.

Comment: I'm getting the error in txteditor.insert(END, content) only, my open file window is opening correctly with the path I mentioned with single \

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `\`. The python interprets it as the escape slash - like the one used for `\n` swap single `\` to the `\\`. I the error you provided you can see `\` with the capital letter. The interpreter tries to escape the highlighted letter.

Comment: What backslash are you specifically talking about? The ones highlighted in the image-of-error are just the result of a dumb syntax highlighter.

Comment: @usr2564301 no, they are not. You can paste that and you will see that it is a wrong file path. in python, the path should be determined with `\\` not with a single one.

Comment: But that path does not appear in the source code. It's in the error message.

Comment: @AleksanderIkleiw I tried as you mentioned in your answer but it was of no help, still getting the same error

Comment: @AleksanderIkleiw I'm getting the error in txteditor.insert(END, content) only my open file window is opening correctly with the path I mentioned with  single \

Comment: im not sure, abt the error, but i believe its because, you are packing and defining in the same variable, try saying `txteditor=Text(root, width=50, height=20)` and in next line say `txteditor.pack()`